# Toggle spans inside an <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function that will toggle optional inputs if chosen, here is what I have done so far:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input>
    <a class="input-toggle" href="#"><span>Toggle Option</span><span>Close</span></a>
    <div class="input-toggle-content">
        <input name="">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.input-toggle').each(function() {
    $(this).next("div").hide().end();
    $("span:last-of-type").hide();
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle();
        $("span:first-of-type").hide();
        $("span:last-of-type").show();
    });
});
```

So, the way it should work is when clicked on .input-toggle the div that is just next to it will be toggled and if clicked again the div will go away... I got this bit working, however, I want to also toggle `<span>Toggle Option</span>` with `<span>Close</span>` and I can't get it working... I don't know if the way I structured my function is correct?

Comment: You don't need `.end()` at the end of a chain.

Comment: Thank you for posting that one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.input-toggle + div.input-toggle-content').hide();
$(".input-toggle span:last-of-type").hide();

$('.input-toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div.input-toggle-content').toggle();
    var spans = $('span', this);
    spans.not(spans.filter(':visible').hide()).show();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DbnW3/)

Comment: That worked brilliantly! Thank you, will accept the answer after the time limit. Ta :)

Comment: 200 reps more for becoming a Trusted User :)

Comment: @AmitJoki Yeah.. waiting for that.. `:)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: don't worry...you will get into it today...congrats :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Thank you very much.. But working intensively in my office now.. Lets see.. And i think we are on the same boat. :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yeah, promised to ship the code by Monday.. That's why i am here now.

Comment: congrats man, it takes effort and knowledge to reach this point! @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: no prob...grab a beer after works...cheers

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jPe3A/

```
$('.input-toggle').each(function() {
    $(this).next("div").hide().end();
    $("span:last-of-type").hide();
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle();
        if($("span:first").is(':hidden')){
            $("span:first").show();
            $("span:last").hide();
        }
        else{
            $("span:first").hide();
            $("span:last").show();
            }
    });
});
```